Extracing C structs into separate files with regex
I am cleaning up a C project which has a single header file that contains all used structs.
I want to extract all structs and put them into separate files using PowerShell Regex.
I have written the following script:
$file = Get-Content -Path "./types.h"
Write-Output $file
$structs = Select-String -Pattern "struct\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*{(?:\s*.*\s*)*?}\s*;" -InputObject $file
Write-Output $structs.Matches.Count
foreach($struct in $structs.Matches) {
    New-Item "./$($struct.groups[1]).h" -Force -Value $struct.Value
}

I have the following test file types.h:
struct foo {

    int a;
};

struct bar{

    short i[200];
};

However, when I run the script, it seems to match the whole file and writes it into a single file foo.h:
struct foo {    int a; };  struct bar{      short i[200]; };

I would expect two files, foo.h and bar.h with the respective structs in them.
My Regex should be working (regex101):


Shouldn't it be foreach($struct in $structs)? I have tested with a string variable though, not a file, i.e. $structs = [regex]::Matches($types, "struct\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*{(?:.*\s*)*?}\s*;")

PowerShell has a (PowerShell) AST parser for that, I would assume that C has something simular...

I suggest you have a couple of other samples. For instance a struct within a struct as well as union within a struct. I'm curious what happens if you have a struct within a union as well.

I was missing the  -AllMatches switch.
I have completed the script the following way (now with enum support):
param (
    [string]$SourceFile,
    [string]$OutputPath
)
$structs = Get-Content -Path $SourceFile -Raw | Select-String -List -Pattern "(?:struct|enum)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*{(?:\s*.*?\s*)*?}\s*;" -AllMatches
foreach($struct in $structs.Matches) {
    Write-Output $struct.Value
    New-Item "$($OutputPath)/$($struct.groups[1].Value.ToLower().Replace('_','')).h" -Force -Value @"
#ifndef $($struct.groups[1].Value.ToUpper())_INCLUDED
#define $($struct.groups[1].Value.ToUpper())_INCLUDED
$($struct.Value)
#endif
"@
}


This works for the simple sample you've presented, but it's gonna break as soon as you consider things like {/} in comments, nested union blocks, etc.

you are right. but it suits my use case and tbh i have never seen any {} brackets in comments (unless a struct/class was commented out)

You weren't just missing the -AllMatches switch, you also needed to match across lines, which required you to pass the whole file content as a single string to Select-String, via Get-Content -Raw ... Note that -List can be omitted, as it is only meaningful with multiple input strings.

C structure definition is not defined by a regular grammar, so it cannot be parsed by a regular expression.
You use .* in your regular expression, which will make the parsing to happen as you define it  (you allow to have } followed by { again inside it).  You have two alternatives here, both capable of failing.  You can use [^}]* insteadof .*, which will make to fail (as it disallows parsing of nested structs, ending at the first } it finds, cutting the rest if it happens you have a nested struct definition)  but will parse correctly unnested structs, Or you can create a regexp (far more complex) that allows a maximum number of nested struct definitions, but this contexts disallows me to provide an example of such approach.
context free grammars are not possible to be parsed with a regular language definition.  You should use a context free parser and a context free grammar. Regular expressions define languages that don't allow nesting of structures.  Only up to a bounded limit (some developers will probably find this approach valid, despite it produces regular expressions bigger as the number of levels of maximum nesting structures increases)

For a more general solution that uses a CFG parser, use Antlr4, the C grammar, Trash, and pwsh or bash. The drawback is that it requires a bit to install.
Step 1 -- Clone the grammar repo
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.git
Cloning into 'grammars-v4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 50583, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1872/1872), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1265/1265), done.
remote: Total 50583 (delta 669), reused 1599 (delta 495), pack-reused 48711
Receiving objects: 100% (50583/50583), 47.49 MiB | 23.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (27090/27090), done.
Updating files: 100% (9413/9413), done.

Step 2 -- Generate a parser for C
$ cd grammars-v4/c
$ trgen -t CSharp
CSharp  C.g4 success 0.0555443
Rendering template file from CSharp/Other.csproj to ./Generated-CSharp/Other.csproj
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.build.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.build.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.build.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.build.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.clean.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.clean.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.clean.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.clean.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.Encodings.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.Encodings.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.ErrorListener.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.ErrorListener.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.makefile to ./Generated-CSharp/st.makefile
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.perf.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.perf.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.ProfilingCommonTokenStream.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.ProfilingCommonTokenStream.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.run.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.run.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.run.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.run.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test-cover.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test-cover.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.Test.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.Test.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/Test.csproj.st to ./Generated-CSharp/Test.csproj.st
Copying source file from C:/msys64/home/Kenne/temp/grammars-v4/c/desc.xml to ./Generated-CSharp/desc.xml
Copying source file from C:/msys64/home/Kenne/temp/grammars-v4/c/C.g4 to ./Generated-CSharp/C.g4
$ cd Generated-CSharp/
$ make
bash build.sh
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\msys64\home\Kenne\temp\grammars-v4\c\Generated-CSharp\Test.csproj (in 526 ms).
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Test -> C:\msys64\home\Kenne\temp\grammars-v4\c\Generated-CSharp\bin\Debug\net8.0\Test.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.56

Step 3 -- Run a script to extract type names, then extract types into appropriately named files
$ cat extract.sh
#!/bin/bash

g=`trparse types.h | trxgrep ' //structOrUnionSpecifier/Identifier/text()' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '\r'`
for f in $g
do
        trparse types.h | trxgrep " //structOrUnionSpecifier[Identifier = '$f']" | trtext > $f.h
done

$ cat types.h


// This is foo.
struct foo {

        int a;
};

// This is bar.
struct bar{

        short i[200];
};
$ bash extract.sh
CSharp 0 types.h success 0.0539358
CSharp 0 types.h success 0.0550352
CSharp 0 types.h success 0.0597384
$ cat foo.h


// This is foo.
struct foo {

        int a;
}
$ cat bar.h


// This is bar.
struct bar{

        short i[200];
}
$

Note, the Powershell-equivalent script is:
$g = trparse types.h | trxgrep ' //structOrUnionSpecifier/Identifier/text()' | Out-String
$g = $g -replace "\n", " "
$g = $g -replace "\r", ""

$g.Trim().Split(" ") | ForEach-Object {
    $f = $_
    trparse types.h | trxgrep " //structOrUnionSpecifier[Identifier = '$f']" | trtext | Out-File "$f.h"
}

